# Как организовать кнопки

Tags: unity3d

В проекте на юнити используется с пару десятков кнопок, у каждой три состояния - обычное, нажатое, не активное. Если на каждое состояние создавать отдельную текстуру, то получится их уж сильно много...Можно как-то сделать кнопки по типу css, где можно все состояния вместить в один графический файл и задавать смещения в этом графическом файле? И насколько этот подход оправдан в Юнити или все же плодить кучу файлов?

Comment: То, о чем вы говорите, называется атлас текстур. И да, это правильный и оптимальный подход.

Comment: Как его использовать, если он уже есть?

Comment: Если вас интересуют исключительно "2д" кнопки -  вам нужен [атлас спрайтов](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteAtlas.html). Если речь про какие-то 3д объекты - это уже сложнее и нужно почитать про батчинг объектов в юнити.